# Movie Clip Frame is extrem low

Tags: movie-clip-editor

Composite movie clip with 3D model.
Iphone 7, 1080P,30FPS,20MB
AMD 7Core，64GB，GTX1070
Blender system Sequencer Cache Limit set 32768
MovieClip saved as the RAMDisk.
Open MovieClip play the 1080P, frame is much lower than expected.
Export MovieClip as 1080P PNG sequence is same low.
Export MovieClip as 720P PNG sequence get a litter better but still lower than 30FPS.
After Motion track ,Solve Camera Motion then click Setup Tracking Scene then total become extrem slow even can not drag the time line .
 Tried Proxy 25%,still same slow.
Whats wrong and how can improve that?
[image]
[image]